# Do terminators ever laugh?

Tags: the-terminator, the-terminator-series

**Has any terminator ever been shown to laugh?** Can they even laugh?

Terminators don't have emotion but they can mimic feelings, such as anger, happiness, etc.

Though since the T-800 had so much trouble with even the concept of a smile, I doubt he (or the other terminators) would feel the need to fake a laugh.

Comment: Arnold laughed all the way to the bank.

Comment: If you consider The Sarah Conner Chronicles canon, I'm somewhat sure that [this](http://img2.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20081104083420/terminator/images/b/be/Happy_Cromartie.jpg) is the Terminator, and not the real guy.

Comment: Arnie can [smirk](http://manilovefilms.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/terminator21.jpg).

Comment: @calccrypto - SCC is canon (as are the various awful sequels).  You can keep denying it, but that doesn't make it not true

Comment: @Richard awww....

Comment: Yes, they do. Look at this GIF from movie T3: http://cdn.yourepeat.com/media/gif/000/240/501/71c70d17f2c37eb656c5c2edf2067e5e.gif

Comment: Can terminators sneeze?

Answer (score 19):

The protector Terminator known as [Cameron](http://terminator.wikia.com/wiki/Cameron), from [The Sarah Connor Chronicles](http://terminator.wikia.com/wiki/Terminator:_The_Sarah_Connor_Chronicles), has laughed on a few occasions.  The first was right at her introduction in 1x01, when she introduces herself to John and pretends to be human.

Another, the screenshot below, is from 1x02, [Gnothi Seauton](http://terminator.wikia.com/wiki/Episode_102:_Gnothi_Seauton), around 15 minutes in.  After Sarah makes a deal with someone, he comments on how quiet Cameron is and then laughs.  Cameron joins in, presumably to try and indicate she's normal, after having been so expressionless.

It looks pretty natural and not forced during the laugh, although the sudden change of expression (both stopping and starting) does look a bit odd:

[image: Cameron laughing]

Answer (score 9):

[Yes, they can do it.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qyTHz9N5KNE)

[And once learned, they understand the message smiling gives (0:14)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0DuZNECHJLo)

[And he does it later again when John instructs him to avoid killing
while preparing for the police assault on Cyberdyne(0:17).](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HkVwEXbR2cU)

But it is a special case because it is after the second T800 had the
chip function enabled which allows him to learn new knowledge. This is
[shown in a deleted scene where the T800 gives instructions to reset the chip
in a garage](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bA66KTGxuAw).

The very good reason given in the movie for the chip lock is that
Terminators could learn too much about humans, something like fascination
and understanding. That would not help solving their mission.

Later models could, like the other answers indicated, mimic smiles better
because of further improvement. Remember that the T600 had rubber skin
and the T800 series had real skin.

Comment: Don't they all have real skin?  I remember something like, only living tissue could travel through time, which was why everyone arrived naked (and being completely encased in skin was why Terminators could travel time)

Comment: @Izkata The answer to that is that T-600s couldn't travel through time; time travelling was not one of a Terminator's primary functions. (This does beg the question how a T-1000 could, though.)

Comment: @MrLister - They can replicate skin on their surface, sufficient to trick the portal into thinking it's biological all over.

Comment: The second and third video links are the same.  Can you fix the third one to link to the right video?

Comment: @WadCheber corrected